# apache cxf-codegen-plugin wsdl2java relative wsdlLocation

Tags: maven, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

I'm able to use generate classes with a relative wsdlLocation when I specify each file, such as 
`<wsdlOptions>
    <wsdlOption>
        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/sample.wsdl</wsdl>
        <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/sample.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
    </wsdlOption>
</wsdlOptions>`

Instead, I would like to use `<wsdlRoot>` so I dont need to specify each wsdl for which to generate classes.

E.g.

`<wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
<includes>
    <include>*.wsdl</include>
</includes>`

This works  to generate classes for each wsdl in the directory, however, the wsdlLocation in the generated class is an absolute path to where the wsdl is located on my machine.  I would like a relative path, so the code is more portable.  Is it possible to specify a relative wsdlLocation when using wsdlRoot?

Thank you

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I just had this problem. I do not want to specify each .wsdl file and still need to set the wsdlLocation to the relative classpath-path.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an extra option `-wsdlLocation` with an empty value. In the generated `XXX_Service` code, it says `WSDL_LOCATION = null;`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/</wsdlRoot>
                <defaultOptions>
                    <defaultExcludesNamespace>true</defaultExcludesNamespace>
                    <extraargs>
                        <extraarg>-wsdlLocation</extraarg>
                        <extraarg> </extraarg>
                    </extraargs>
                </defaultOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You can find similar excerpt in `pom.xml` of my previous CXF project here: https://github.com/htr3n/loan-approval-portal/blob/master/pom.xml.